# How do I input data with my own in this d3 bubble chart in react?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

so in React, I copy and pasted a d3 bubble chart element without knowing too much about react. I input data into the bubble chart with my own json data. When I run it though, it gives "can not read from undefined"  because of d.data.Name.substring(0, d.r / 3). i feel like I am not defining my my json object correctly (d3.hierachy and some functions appears to be asking for a children or something), here are my codes:

RoadmapList.json:

```
    [
  {
    "Name": "Computer Science",
    "Count": 4156
  },

  {
    "Name": "Home Economics",
    "Count": 689
  },
  {
    "Name": "Venture Capital Investment",
    "Count": 890
  },
  {
    "Name": "Fabric design",
    "Count": 167
  },
  {
    "Name": "Deep Learning Researchers",
    "Count": 812
  }
]
```

And in Bubble.js, my bubble chart component, by the way, when I use states, it works, but since I want dynamic update, I am using this.props.roadmapdata

Bubble.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Bubble extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    d3.select("nodes").remove("nodes");
    var diameter = 600;

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var bubble = d3
      .pack(this.props.RoadmapData)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(1.5);

    var svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .attr("class", "bubble");

    var node = svg
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(this.props.RoadmapData)
      .enter()
      .filter(function(d) {
        return !d.children;
      })
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
    node.append("title").text(function(d) {
      return d.Name + ": " + d.Count;
    });

    node
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    node
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".2em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.Name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
      })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "white");

    node
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1.3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.Count;
      })
      .attr("font-family", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "white");
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.node}</div>;
  }
}

export default Bubble;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using bubble chart and react using [d3.packSiblings](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#packSiblings).

The `<svg>` element has a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) , so when the component is mounted you can use d3 to create/update/remove the elements.

Note:

`dataForPacking` is just a map to create the attributes require by d3 packing, such as, r,x,z, then your data Name, Count.

There is an input box, to illustrate the setState updating the initial props data with new data and re-rendering the bubble.
There are many better ways to do this, but this is a good start.

```js
const dataJSON = [
  {
    Name: "Computer Science",
    Count: 4156
  },

  {
    Name: "Home Economics",
    Count: 689
  },
  {
    Name: "Venture Capital Investment",
    Count: 890
  },
  {
    Name: "Fabric design",
    Count: 167
  },
  {
    Name: "Deep Learning Researchers",
    Count: 812
  }
];

const dataForPacking = (data) => {
    return {
      r: data.Count,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      Count: data.Count,
      Name: data.Name
    };
};

class Bubble extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: this.props.size[0],
      height: this.props.size[1],
      data: this.props.data
    };
    this.svgRef = React.createRef();
    this.drawBubble = this.drawBubble.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawBubble()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawBubble()
  }
  drawBubble = () => {
    const svg = d3.select(this.svgRef.current);
    svg.select("g").remove();
    const diameter = 600;

    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    const circles = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "circles")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        `translate(${this.state.width / 2},
          ${this.state.height / 2})scale(0.02)`
      );

    const node = circles
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(d3.packSiblings(this.state.data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    node.append("title").text(function(d) {
      return d.Name + ": " + d.Count;
    });

    node
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    node
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".2em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.Name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
      })
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "white");

    node
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1.3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.Count;
      })
      .attr("font-family", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "white");
  };
  keyPress = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      const newDataArray = event.currentTarget.value.split(",");
      if(!newDataArray[1] || isNaN(newDataArray[1])){
        return; 
      }
      const newData = {
        Name: newDataArray[0],
        Count: Number(newDataArray[1])
      };
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: [...prevState.data, dataForPacking(newData)]
      }))
      event.currentTarget.value = "";
    }
  };
  reset = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: this.props.data.map(e => dataForPacking(e))
      }))
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Name, Count </span>
        <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.keyPress} />
        <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
        <svg
          ref={this.svgRef}
          width={this.props.size[0]}
          height={this.props.size[1]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Bubble data={dataJSON.map(e=> dataForPacking(e))} size={[600, 200]} />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"><div>
```

Comment: Thanks, cal_br_mar, I will implement this solution this afternoon!